# What does "NOOPd" mean for micrometer.io?

Tags: micrometer

When reading about [3.1. Composite registries](http://micrometer.io/docs/concepts) I see this:

> Increments are NOOPd until there is a registry in the composite. The
>   counter’s count will still yield 0 at this point.

What does NOOPd mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A [NO-OP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP_(code)) is a piece of code that does nothing ("no operation"). By extension, "to NO-OP something" means to make it do nothing. "NO-OP'd" (spelled "NOOPd" here) is the past participle. Perhaps "disabled" would be easier to understand.

What it means is that `compositeCounter.increment();` does nothing until a registry is added. Before that point, the count will stay 0 no matter how often you call `increment()`.

As the example shows:

```java
CompositeMeterRegistry composite = new CompositeMeterRegistry();

Counter compositeCounter = composite.counter("counter");
compositeCounter.increment();  // (1)

SimpleMeterRegistry simple = new SimpleMeterRegistry();
composite.add(simple);  // (2)

compositeCounter.increment();  // (3)
```

Before a registry is added in step 2, the `increment()` call in step 1 is a NO-OP. Only step 3 actually increments the counter (from `0` to `1`).

Comment: "is the past participle" is enough for me